# Authentification error when trying to pull base image from Docker Hub using Dockerfile and podman

Tags: docker, authentication, dockerfile, dockerhub, podman

I would like to create an image that is based on `ubuntu:focal` from **dockerhub**. I have edited `/etc/containers/registries.conf` to include `docker.io` (it's a bit confusing to me why it's the top-level domain is this compared to `hub.docker.com` for the website but never mind):

```
unqualified-search-registries = ["docker.io", "quay.io"]
```

I created an access token in my Docker Hub profile and ran

```
podman login -u USERNAME --authfile auth.json
```

inside the directory where my `Dockerfile` is so that I have everything bundled together. This creates an authentification configuration file similar to this one:

```
{
    "auths": {
        "docker.io": {
            "auth": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    }
}
```

which can then be used for the building:

```
podman build --authfile=./auth.json .
```

The above command is executed from within the same directory. When I run it I get a menu with two options (`docker.io` and `quay.io`) since those are the registries I have configured to be available to my local installation. Once I choose `docker.io` I get

```
STEP 1/5: FROM ubunut:focal
? Please select an image: 
  ▸ docker.io/library/ubunut:focal
    quay.io/ubunut:focal

✔ docker.io/library/ubunut:focal
Trying to pull docker.io/library/ubunut:focal...
Error: error creating build container: initializing source docker://ubunut:focal: reading manifest focal in docker.io/library/ubunut: errors:
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
unauthorized: authentication required
```

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubunut:focal

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y locales && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && localedef -i en_US -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.utf8
```

I'm quite new to creating images so my mistake is probably obvious. It is definitely not in the `Dockerfile` itself (although errors are not excluded) since the building process fails at the step 1 - pulling the base image.

Comment: typo, you have ubun*ut*, not ubun*tu*.

Comment: Yeap.. Just saw it. Still will leave the question even if it costs me rep so that others can learn from it. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will not delete the answer as silly as my mistake is so that other can learn from it. Also the question provides instructions how to login and use authentification files, which imho is not that obvious when reading the podman documentation on this matter.

It's **ubuntu** and not **ubunut**. A simple typo yet fatal.

Comment: Bro thank you a lot I made a type as well and was searching around the Internet thinking why I couldn't do it, I learnt something from you.